# EF Core property value conversion not working in a derived entity configuration

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a generic EF BaseEntityConfiguration class that is used for setting up base properties (like the primary key, properties used for soft deletion, query filters, etc.) and a derived configuration for an entity that stores System.Type and a JSON property. If I don't use the generic class and just implement the IEntityTypeConfiguration then the value conversion works and there are no errors. However if I inherit from the base class, I get EF Core issues about saving Type and object without any conversion. Other configurations that inherit from the base class and don't need conversions work fine.

The error:

`Error: The property 'MessageLog.Data' could not be mapped because it is of type 'object', which is not a supported primitive type or a valid entity type. Either explicitly map this property, or ignore it using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.`

```
public class MessageLogConfiguration
        //: IEntityTypeConfiguration<MessageLog>
        : BaseEntityConfiguration<MessageLog, int>
    {
        public MessageLogConfiguration(ILogger<MessageLogConfiguration> logger)
           : base(logger)
        { }

        public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<MessageLog> builder)
        {
            base.Configure(builder);

            //builder
            //    .HasKey(x => x.Id);


            builder
                .Property(m => m.MessageId)
                .IsRequired();

            builder
                .Property(m => m.Data)
                .HasJsonConversion()
                .IsRequired();

            builder
                .Property(m => m.Type)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasConversion(
                    t => t.AssemblyQualifiedName,
                    t => Type.GetType(t!)!);

            builder.HasIndex(m => m.MessageId).IsUnique();

        }
    }
```

```
public abstract class BaseEntityConfiguration<TEntity, TId> : IEntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity>
        where TEntity : Entity<TId>
        where TId : struct
    {
        protected BaseEntityConfiguration(ILogger<BaseEntityConfiguration<TEntity, TId>> logger)
        {
            this.Logger = logger;
        }

        protected ILogger<BaseEntityConfiguration<TEntity, TId>> Logger { get; }

        public virtual void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> builder)
        {
            builder
                .HasKey(x => x.Id);

            if (typeof(IAuditableEntity).IsAssignableFrom(builder.Metadata.ClrType))
            {
                Logger.LogTrace($" > Configure properties for {nameof(IAuditableEntity)}'");
                builder.Property(nameof(IAuditableEntity.CreatedOn)).IsRequired().ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
                builder.Property(nameof(IAuditableEntity.CreatedBy)).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(255);
                builder.Property(nameof(IAuditableEntity.ModifiedOn)).IsRequired(false);
                builder.Property(nameof(IAuditableEntity.ModifiedBy)).IsRequired(false).HasMaxLength(255);
            }

            if (typeof(ISoftDeletableEntity).IsAssignableFrom(builder.Metadata.ClrType))
            {
                Logger.LogTrace($" > Configure properties for {nameof(ISoftDeletableEntity)}'");
                builder.Property(nameof(ISoftDeletableEntity.DeletedAt)).IsRequired(false);
                builder.Property(nameof(ISoftDeletableEntity.DeletedBy)).IsRequired(false);
                builder.HasQueryFilter(m => EF.Property<int?>(m, nameof(ISoftDeletableEntity.DeletedBy)) == null);
            }
        }
    }
```

```
public class MessageLog : AuditableEntity<int>
    {
        public MessageLog(string messageId, object data, MessageLogType messageLogType)
        {
            this.MessageId = messageId;
            this.Type = data.GetType();
            this.Data = data;
            this.MessageLogType = messageLogType;
        }

        private MessageLog(string messageId)
        {
            this.MessageId = messageId;
            this.Type = default!;
            this.Data = default!;
            this.MessageLogType = default!;
        }



        public string MessageId { get; private set; }

        public Type Type { get; private set; }

        public MessageLogType MessageLogType { get; private set; }

        public object Data { get; private set; }
    }
```

```
public static class ValueConversionExtensions
    {
        public static PropertyBuilder<T> HasJsonConversion<T>(this PropertyBuilder<T> propertyBuilder)
            where T : class, new()
        {
            ValueConverter<T, string> converter = new ValueConverter<T, string>
            (
                v => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(v),
                v => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(v) ?? new T()
            );

            ValueComparer<T> comparer = new ValueComparer<T>
            (
                (l, r) => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(l) == JsonConvert.SerializeObject(r),
                v => v == null ? 0 : JsonConvert.SerializeObject(v).GetHashCode(),
                v => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(v))
            );

            propertyBuilder.HasConversion(converter);
            propertyBuilder.Metadata.SetValueConverter(converter);
            propertyBuilder.Metadata.SetValueComparer(comparer);
            propertyBuilder.HasColumnType("jsonb");

            return propertyBuilder;
        }
    }
```

DbContext

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the other scenarios working but not this specific one. It's obviously that the `Data` property is not ignored and its type is `object` so the exception makes sense. Could you point out any other working scenarios in which you have a property of `object` that is mapped to some column in your db table?

Comment: The thing is I don't want to ignore it. The Data property which is of type object is changed via the HasJsonConversion() to a 'jsonb' column in the db model. It is working fine if I directly implement IEntityTypeConfiguration<MessageLog> but if I inherit the base class which is implementing this interface then for some reason value converters are ignored. Same thing goes for the Type property but only the error is a bit different (something along the lines of "You need a primary key defined for this entity.").

Comment: Can you try debugging the derived configuration to see if it's actually run? I doubt there is something wrong with the `ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly`, for that possible cause, try applying your derived configuration directly instead.

Comment: I just tried couple of things regarding applying the configuration like you said and in the process of manually adding the derived configuration I removed the logger from BaseEntityConfiguration's constructor. This somehow fixed the problem and it is working with ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly as well. I'm just not sure why this configuration would only work with an empty constructor but the others that don't have any object properties (or value conversions) work with the logger passed in the constructor.

Comment: I think the `ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly` does not support DI for `IEntityTypeConfiguration` because it creates the instance using the parameterless constructor. It may also support DI but in that case you can try registering your derived configuration type as singleton manually to see if it works (just guessing, this scenario is tricky because usually we have a parameterless constructor for the configuration class and it just works)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### TL;DR

Try adding an empty constructor to your `IEntityTypeConfiguration` implementations. Otherwise, if you still want to use DI in your entity type configurations, it might be worth looking at [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/23103).

---

I don't think the injected logger in your `IEntityTypeConfiguration` will work out together with `ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly`. From [the source code](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/9a8c6c750d5166b7ae4423b3ceb05da2bf6561f3/src/EFCore/ModelBuilder.cs) of that method, it seems that while using reflection to search for the configuration classes it requires an empty constructor so that it can instantiate them.

[image: EF core source code for ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly]

Since your `IEntityTypeConfiguration`s lack a default empty constructor, the `ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly` is probably not picking them up.

If you still want to use DI in your entity type configurations, it might be worth looking at [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/23103), where **@ajcvickers** gives a detailed explanation on how to do it.

This is a copy/pasta of the Github issue answer code:

```
public abstract class EntityTypeConfigurationDependency
{
    public abstract void Configure(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
}

public abstract class EntityTypeConfigurationDependency<TEntity>
    : EntityTypeConfigurationDependency, IEntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity> 
    where TEntity : class
{
    public abstract void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> builder);

    public override void Configure(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
        => Configure(modelBuilder.Entity<TEntity>());
}

public class Blog
{
    public int Pk { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class BlogConfiguration : EntityTypeConfigurationDependency<Blog>
{
    public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Blog> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(e => e.Pk);
    }
}

public class Post
{
    public int Pk { get; set; }
    public Blog Blog { get; set; }
}

public class PostConfiguration : EntityTypeConfigurationDependency<Post>
{
    public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Post> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(e => e.Pk);
    }
}

public class Program
{
    private static ILoggerFactory ContextLoggerFactory
        => LoggerFactory.Create(b => b.AddConsole().SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Information));

    public static void Main()
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddDbContext<SomeDbContext>(
                b => b.UseSqlServer(Your.ConnectionString)
                    .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                    .UseLoggerFactory(ContextLoggerFactory));
        
        foreach (var type in typeof(SomeDbContext).Assembly.DefinedTypes
            .Where(t => !t.IsAbstract
                        && !t.IsGenericTypeDefinition
                        && typeof(EntityTypeConfigurationDependency).IsAssignableFrom(t)))
        {
            services.AddSingleton(typeof(EntityTypeConfigurationDependency), type);
        }

        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        
        using (var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope())
        {
            var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<SomeDbContext>();

            context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
            context.Database.EnsureCreated();
        }
    }
}

public class SomeDbContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<EntityTypeConfigurationDependency> _configurations;

    public SomeDbContext(
        DbContextOptions<SomeDbContext> options,
        IEnumerable<EntityTypeConfigurationDependency> configurations)
        : base(options)
    {
        _configurations = configurations;
    }

    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        foreach (var entityTypeConfiguration in _configurations)
        {
            entityTypeConfiguration.Configure(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, man! Yours and @KingKong's answers were extremely helpful and got me on right path. I guess the whole issue was that you can't really inject something with the default entity configuration. I ended up creating my own implementation of entity configuration with its own interface and a base class with a virtual Configure method. Then I registered every configuration and injected them into DbContext. In the DbContext's OnModelCreating I foreached them and called Configure() on each. That did the trick and this way I can inject as much things as I want into the configuration.

Comment: @VeselinTodorov that's great to hear! 